# save model int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have two forms I sent to a template and when I got them all models were retrieved and saved, but the last model takes all the other models and save itself, also it does not save itself. I get an error like this below. Can anyone help me out please?

```
Exception Type:  TypeError
Exception Value:  int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'
```

I tracked it down and the problem look like just one in put from the form there is how it look from the form

```
class AForm(ModelForm):
    mentancy_fee = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
```

and here his its defination from the model

```
class AgentLandLordContract(models.Model):
    mentancy_fee = models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=True,null = True)
```

so why is this form field returning a tuple and not an it.I blocked out just this filed from the form and all is well

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Comment: Please, can you give us more details about? Maybe some code of your view? It would be useful to see how you are managing the process of saving those two forms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in the form i left a comma at the end of a field this made the form input into a tuple and when i found it all was ok

```
mentancy_fee = forms.IntegerField(required=False),
```